# Teradata SQL: How to use SUM function to Sum total into 2 groups depending on whether case A or B?

Tags: sum, case, aggregate-functions, teradata

```
SELECT
    Account,
    CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN SUM(Amount) END AS Type1_tot,
    CASE WHEN Type = 2 THEN SUM(Amount) END AS Type2_tot
FROM Table
```

> Error - Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Please find a table of data and expected results below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, and instead sum over your `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT
    Account,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type1_tot,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Type2_tot
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Account
```